# Django Filter Objects and Get First Corresponding Values

Tags: python, django

I have two models.

```
class House(models.Model):
    name= models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    city= models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    area= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class HouseRooms(models.Model):
    room_name=models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    house= models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='house_hr')
    room_price=models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

When a user run a keyword search, I want to return the name of each 'House' and the first room_price of the corresponding 'HouseRooms'. See my views below.

```
def my_house_search(request):
    query_string= ''
    rms= None
    sms=None
    if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
        query_string = request.GET['q']

        entry_query= get_query(query_string, ['city','country',])

        rms= House.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('-pub_date')
        sms= HouseRooms.objects.filter(house_id__in=rms)


        return render(request, 'search/my_house_search.html',{'rms':rms, 'sms':sms, 'query_string':query_string})
```

Template:

```
 {% if query_string %}
     <p> Results </p>


     {% if rms %}
      {% for m in rms %}
         <p> Name: {{ m.name }} </p>
      {% empty %}
          <p> No house found </p>
      {% endfor %}

      {% for sd in sms %}
        <p> price: {{ sd.room_price }} for {{sd.room_name}}</p>
      {% empty %}
         <p> no price found </p>
      {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
```

With the code I wrote, it will return the name of each house and show all prices to all houses like this:

```
Coker House

Klopp House

$50/day for small room
$100/day for medium room
$200/day for big room

$200/day for quack room
$400/day for master room
$500/day for big room
```

I just want it to return the result like this.

```
Coker House
$50/day for small room

Klopp House
$200/day for quack room
```

What am I missing? How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't query HouseRooms explicitly in the view. Instead, you can use the reverse relationship accessor inside your iteration in the template itself.

```
{% for m in rms %}
  <p> Name: {{ m.name }} </p>
  {% with m.house_hr.first as sd %}
    {% if sd %}
      <p> price: {{ sd.room_price }} for {{sd.room_name}}</p>
    {% else %}
      <p> no price found </p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
{% empty %}
  <p> No house found </p>
{% endfor %}
```